# Memory Leak in Sqlite3 database in Linux Qt

Tags: qt, memory-management, memory-leaks, sqlite, arm

I know this question has been answered, but still i didn't get the right resolution of this problem.

I am developing an application for ARM9 based microprocessor using UBUNTU 12.10.

I have used Sqlite3.8.3 for data management.

I have experienced the memory leak in database. I have followed Following to cases.

> **CASE-1** - Suppose Memory Leak is done by QSql Driver`. So that I have
> implemented the following code for simple insert method.

```
QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(sqliteCon);

query->prepare("QUERY FOR INSERTING INTO THE DATABASE");

if(query->exec())
{
    QString retVal = query->lastInsertId().toString();
    
    query->finish();
    query->clear();
}
delete query;
sqliteCon.close();
```

**But It still does not free the memory. So I have tried to use the sqlite3 library directly through simple c code.**

> **CASE-2** Directly using the Sqlite3.8 library for insert method.
>
> Code Example

```
sqlite3 *db;


rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
if( rc )
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  exit(0);
}
else
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
}

sprintf("QUERY FOR INSERT");

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlquery, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
if( rc != SQLITE_OK )
{
  fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
}
else
{
  fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
}
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
sqlite3_close(db);
```

**It still does not free the memory.**

What to do ?
There is an options of **SQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT** , **CACHE_SIZE** .
Should i use this options ?
If yes then how i can compile Sqlite using these options ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What memory do you think is leaked?

Comment: I am using 64Mb RAM . When I executes the query it uses around 4kb RAM. after that it never release that RAM.

Comment: How do you measure that?

Comment: I observe this using the TOP command. and check that when ever insert statement it consumes the RAM. But never freed it.

Comment: Don't rely on top. You should run your application under Valgrind and check if memory really leaks.

Comment: I have tried to use integrated Valgrind tool of QT. but did not get too much information. Still i googled for this problem and it is there.